# How to control tagging with multiple VLAN in the same bridge using Netplan on Ubuntu 20

Tags: 20.04, virtualization, netplan, vlan, tagging

If I have 2 VLAN (10, and 20) on an Ethernet interface (say eno1), I can create 2 bridges and configure a VLAN in each. Any VM connecting to these Bridges (virtual interface eth0/eth1) receives untagged frames from each virtual interface. Transmitted frames have the VLAN pushed on by each virtual interface.
If I repeat the above but put 2 VLAN in the same bridge, any VM connecting to that bridge will receive tagged frames and expect to transmit tagged frames.
So, what if I want VLAN 10 to deliver untagged frames, and say VLAN 20 to show up tagged. How can I do that? The fundamental question is, how do I control tagging of VLAN on virtual interfaces in VM?